# How to fix resize video HTML in webview?

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode, webview

how to fix this video in webview with HTML code , i use WordPress app

```
import UIKit

class ShowAricleVCViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!

    var Content : String!



    override func viewDidLoad() {


    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let TheHtmlAfter = HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: Content)

            webview.loadHTMLString(TheHtmlAfter, baseURL: nil)

    }



    func HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: String) -> String {
        let htmlString: String = "<html> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><head><style>body { background: white } p { color: #555555; font-family: 'Avenir-Book'; font-size: 14px } img { border-radius: 8px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 220px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} </style></head><body><img align=\"middle\" > <p>\(HTMLString)<p></body></html>"
        return htmlString
    }
```

this code just fixed picture and font and background 
i need to fix video scle

```
   func HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: String) -> String {
        let htmlString: String = "<html> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><head><style>body { background: white } p { color: #555555; font-family: 'Avenir-Book'; font-size: 14px } img { border-radius: 8px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 220px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} </style></head><body><img align=\"middle\" > <p>\(HTMLString)<p></body></html>"
        return htmlString
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: An example of html I used just playing around to get a youtube video cosmetically working properly. "<html><body><p align=\"center\"><iframe src=\"\(youtubeURL)\" width=\"\(UIScreen.main.bounds.width > 1024 ? "\(width!)" : "85%")\" height=\"\(height)\" margin=\"0 auto\" allowfullscreen></iframe></p></body></html>"

Comment: why you're not calling super on the overrides

Comment: I want to have minimized the size of the video screen according to size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: String) -> String {
        let htmlString: String = "<html> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><head><style>body { background: white } p { color: #555555; font-family: 'Avenir-Book'; font-size: 14px } img { border-radius: 8px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 220px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} iframe { border-radius: 8px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 220px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} </style></head><body><img align=\"middle\" > <p><div dir='rtl'><center>\(HTMLString)</center></div><p></body></html>"
        return htmlString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question 100%. But if all you need is to markup the video in HTML in a way that is responsive and maintains its aspect ratio, I once came across this helpful post and have been using it ever since:

https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: I want to have minimized the size of the video screen according to size

Comment: Well you could still use this blog post and just make the outer container 100% size of the window

Comment: Well what write here adjusts ?                                                                   func HTMLImageCorrector(HTMLString: String) -> String {
        let htmlString: String = "<html> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><head><style>body { background: white } p { color: #555555; font-family: 'Avenir-Book'; font-size: 14px } img { border-radius: 8px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 220px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} </style></head><body><img align=\"middle\" > <p>\(HTMLString)<p></body></html>"
        return htmlString
    }

Comment: I thought we were talking about a video ? This snippet only contains an image ?